# Theorem formulation "Given ..., then ..." or "For all ..., ..."?

Tags: proof-writing

When formulating a theorem, which of the following forms would be preferred, and why? Or is there another even better formulation? Are there reasons for or against mixing them in one paper?

Formulation 0: If $x\in X$, then (expression involving $x$).

Formulation 1: Given $x$ in $X$, then (expression involving $x$).

Formulation 2: For all $x$ in $X$ it holds that (expression involving $x$).

Comment: I used the 'proof-writing' tag because no other tag I found seemed appropriate, and I cannot create new ones.

Comment: They're all equivalent. Use what reads best. If you can give a concrete example, perhaps we can help you choose.

Comment: @lhf: I've added an extra subquestion regarding mixing them in one paper.

Comment: Why not examine a few papers you like, and see what is done there?  Then see if you can tell *why* you like them.

Comment: "For all $x$ in $X$ it holds that $\dots$" sounds to me like something transliterated from a language other than English.

Answer (score 1):

Formulation 0 confounds the binding of the symbol $x$ as a variable to $X$ with set inclusion $x\in X$.

The other two formulations are equivalent, but the second seems stronger and is more verbose, so for now I prefer Formulation 2.

Comment: Whu? 0 and 2 are obviously equivalent. Compare the following two definitions of continuity at $x_0 \in \mathbb R$: $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 : |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon,$$ and $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta): |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: @kahen: the ‘$\in$’ in ‘$\forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$’ is not set inclusion from a formal point of view; this is what I was referring to. (Cf. the often-made distinction between equality ‘$=$’ and definition ‘$:=$’.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm a simpleton, I always preferred a theorem stated memorably:

**Theorem 1.** Even numbers are interesting.

Compared to...

**Theorem 2.** If $x$ is an even number, then $x$ is interesting.

...which is long-winded; or...

**Theorem 3.** Given an even number $x$, $x$ is interesting.

Theorem 3 also has odd consonance (writing "...$x$, $x$ is ..." seems like bad style).

**Theorem 4.** For all even numbers $x$, we have $x$ be interesting.

This also suffers from peculiar consonance ("we have $x$ be interesting" is quite alien, despite being proper grammar).

Theorem 1 has a quick and succinct enunciation ("Even numbers are interesting"), the proof can begin with a specification "Let $x$ be an even number. Then [proof omitted]."

Also we see theorem 1 has additional merit: it avoids needless symbols.

There is one warning I should give: each theorem is different. Some theorems can be stated beautifully without symbols (e.g., theorem 1). Others cannot be coherently stated *without* symbols. There is not "iron law" on how theorems should be formulated; it's a case-by-case problem.